# Nested 3 level LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Here is my working **SQL** query I want write **LINQ** to 
I have no idea to convert write 3 level nested query

```
Select *
from demo.dbo.Account
where accType = 3
and LinkAcc IN (
  select accNum
  from demo.dbo.Account
  here inkAcc IN (
    select accNum
    from demo.dbo.Account
    where memberid = 20
    and accType= 0 
  )
  and accType = 2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing LINQ equivalents to a SQL `IN()`, you have to think about it in reverse.

Rather than the SQL

> where entity-value IN sub-values

the LINQ expression becomes

> where sub-values contains entity-value

Because writing this in one monolithic LINQ statement is mind-bending, I have broken each subquery into a separate variable.

```
using System.Linq;

public IEnumerable<Account> FilterAccounts(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)

  // start with the deepest subquery first
  var memberAccountNums = accounts
    .Where(x => x.MemberId == 20 && x.AccType == 0)
    .Select(x => x.AccNum)
    .ToArray();

  var linkAccountNums = accounts
    .Where(x => x.AccType == 2 && memberAccountNums.Contains(x.AccNum))
    .Select(x => x.AccNum)
    .ToArray();

  var result = accounts
    .Where(x => x.AccType == 3 && linkAccountNums.Contains(x.AccNum))
    .ToArray();

  return result;
}
```

I have used a method here to demonstrate a compilable version of the code (assuming the class and property names are correct). You would obviously want to parameterise this to meet your needs.

If you want to combine them for some reason (say LINQ-to-SQL), then you could write it as one query, or you could instead use a series of `IQueryable` variables instead of calling `.ToArray()`.

I have created a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pg0WLC

I assume that the logic is you want to return all accounts with AccType 3 where there is also a matching AccNum for AccType 0 and 2? This assumes that the MemberId property will match if the AccNum properties do.

Another way of doing this with LINQ would be to use group by:

```
int[] types = new int[] { 0, 2, 3 };

return accounts
  .Where(x => x.MemberId == 20 && types.Contains(x.AccType))          
  .GroupBy(x => x.AccNum)
  .Where(x => x.Count() == types.Count())         
  .SelectMany(x => x)
  .Where(x => x.AccType == 3);
```

Comment: Sorry now I get error it said Account does not contain 'Where'. I added  using System.Linq; to Account class directive i tried to write LINQ query they also gives error  Where not contain

Comment: I stated my assumption at the top that the variable account is of type IEnumerable<Account>. Can you add more context to your question if you need more specific help

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working demo and an alternative method

Comment: In debugging memberAccountNums returns {string[2]} but after that linkAccountsNums returns string {string[0]} = means null  by my sqlquery's 2.nd level  this should return   3 values

Comment: memberAccountNums.Contains() is realy working ? instead of sql's ' IN ' keyword.  It looks bool method return T F

Comment: @Baganaakh SQL: `Value IN (1,2,3)`. C#: `[1,2,3].Contains(Value)`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8